# Javascript not creating object

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to define an array of objects, each of which contains an object within text in javascript. I have the following code

```
testState={id : 'blahdu3', 
states:  [{ 
    simulation : {
        num_devices: 14,
        num_networks: 6,
        simulation_name: 'Jeffs sim',
        id : 'blahdu3',
        config_map : {
            'Partition1': {
                'networka' : { 'devicea' : '1',  'deviceb@mun.ca': '2', 'devicec@mun.ca':'3'},
                'networkb' : { 'deviced': '4', 'devicee': '5'},
            },
            'Partition2':{ 
                'networkc' :{ 'devicef': '6', 'deviceg@mun.ca' : '7',  'deviceh@mun.ca': '8'},
                'networkd' :{'devicei@mun.ca':'9', 'device@mun.ca': '10'},
                'networkTest' :{},
            },
            'Partition3':{ 
                'networke' : { 'devicek':'11'} 
            },
            'freelist' : {'devicew': '13', 'evicex' : '14'}
        }
    }, 
    timestamp: '2015-01-012:44:00',
 }]
}
```

The problem is that when I attempt to call this "configMap" with                                                                                              states[i].simulation.configMap;
I am told that the configMap is a null object. Can anyone clarify what's going on here for me?
Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: You should call `states[i].simulation.config_map` not `states[i].simulation.configMap`

Comment: `configMap` or `config_map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `testState.states[i].simulation.config_map` instead of `testState.states[i].simulation.configMap`

Comment: that was emberassing. Working with other people's code gets messy haha sorry for being an idiot

Answer (score 1):

use this for first element

```
testState.states[0].simulation.config_map;
```

or

```
testState.states[i].simulation.config_map;
```